# Mixed-Integer Bilinear Program (MIBLP)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

Consider the problem of

\begin{align}
\min_{x,y} \quad &a^Tx + b^Ty + x^TQy \\
&Ax \leq d \\
&Cy \leq e \\
&x_i \in \mathbb{R} \quad i \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\} \\
&y_i \in {\{0,1\}} \quad i \in \{1,2,\ldots,M\}
\end{align}
where $x = [x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N]^T$, $y = [y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N]^T$, $a, b,d,e$ are real-valued vectors with appropriate dimensions, and $A,C,Q$ are real-valued matrices with appropriate dimensions. Is it possible to find optimum (local/global) solution to this Mixed-Integer Bilinear Program (MIBLP). Is there any solver for this type of problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO! Some definitions are still lacking from the post; Who's $A$, $B$? Matrices? Real, complex? If you can edit to define it, people can more easily access it and read it.

Comment: @AmirSagiv Thanks for your comment. I edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried the nonlinear solvers from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software

Comment: @joro No, wasn't aware of them. Thanks